# fs.existsSync is not a function when importing electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I'm currently using Vue and [Electron](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) and would like to restart the application using

```
import { app } from 'electron';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  methods: {
   restartApp() {
      app.relaunch()
      app.exit()
   }
  }
}
```

But when I'm importing electron I'm getting `fs.existsSync is not a function`

I also tried using

```
const remote = require('electron');

import { app } from remote;
```

and also

```
const remote = window.require('electron')
```

returns me `window.require is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of preload argument in webPreferences while creating the main BrowserWindow.
In the main.js,

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

In the preload.js

```
    const remote = require("electron").remote;
    window.appQuit = function() {
      remote.app.exit(0);
    };
```